# inconsistent cursor size over certain apps/windows

Tags: monitor, cinnamon, hdpi

when hovering over certain apps, specifically obs studio and the thinkorswim desktop app, my mouse mouse cursor becomes enlarged until i hover/enter out of focus of that window.

in this first photo, you can see that it is my normal cursor.
[image: in this first photo, you can see that it is my normal cursor.]

and in the second hovering over the thinkorswim app, the cursor gets bigger. the cursor gets bigger when i hover over obs too.
[image: and in the second hovering over the thinkorswim app, the cursor gets bigger. the cursor gets bigger when i hover over obs too.]

this may be a cinnamon desktop issue with high dpi monitors because i never had this issue on gnome.
i have already tried manually setting my mouse cursor theme through command prompt, and entering dconf and manually changing my mouse cursor. tried enabling and disabling fractional scaling in displays (though i dont think that does anything in relation to my cursor), and nothing seemed to work.

most of the solutions i have tried - https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=339068

p.s. i am using a widescreen, 3440x1440 (24:9) monitor

Comment: Not a Cinnamon-only issue. I'm experiencing the same under GNOME: cursor is enormous over Nautilus, for example

Comment: ah, do you know the issue? its super annoying. i also noticed that is happens at the login screen aswell